# What's the reference name if a bean is defined in xml without id specified?

Tags: java, spring

Say I have a bean definition like this:

```
<bean class="com.xxx.CustomerSecurityManager"/>
```

I have another class has the reference of `SecurityManager` like this:

```
 private SecurityManager<?> securityManager = null;

@Autowired
public void setSecurityManager(SecurityManager<?> securityManager) {
    this.securityManager = securityManager;
}
```

The `SecurityManager` is an interface, and the `CustomerSecurityManager` implements it.

My question is how `SecurityManager` is injected in this class above. Form what I know the `securityManager` here refers to `CustomerSecurityManager`.

So, what's the reference name without id is defined in xml? Does it use the super class or interface as its reference name?

Comment: Spring checks whether there are beans implementing the interface. If only one is found it's assigned. If more than one such bean exists you need to specify name in qualifier

Comment: For my case, the `CustomerSecurityManager` extends `DefaultSecurityManager` and implements `SecurityManager`, so the `SecurityManager` should be assigned?